# Filter Array by containment in other array in ng-repeat loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, json

How can i filter the results of an array based on an other array in ng-repeat.

Array i want to filter:

```
[
    [
    'gender': 'male',
    'languages': ['German', 'English'],
    'country': 'Marocco'
    ],
    [
    'gender': 'female',
    'languages': ['German', 'French'],
    'country': 'Kosovo'
    ]
]
```

I want to to filter by this object:

```
   | filter:{'languages': ['Urdu', 'French'], 'country': ['Kosovo']}
```

Expected result:

```
[
'gender': 'female',
'languages': ['German', 'French'],
'country': 'Kosovo'
]
```

Comment: But you **can't** have *object of arrays* in javascript...

Comment: @JSelser Technically you can as you can have arrays of arrays and arrays are objects.

Comment: Anyway the noted objects have invalid syntax.

Comment: can you please be more precise?

Comment: Someone edited the question but it's still invalid syntax... You **can't** have something like `[ 'something': 'something' ]`

Comment: i think u just dont get it! obviously the syntax isnt correct, bcs. this will not work, but i am asking for a solution to make it work. i where thinking something like a custom filter or similar?

Comment: Yheap, I don't get it. I could easily make your filter function if your data made sense **but it doesn't**. If you also need help structuring your data, please say so

Comment: well please tell me specific what is wrong with the way the data is structured? which part except the filter is wrong? Obviously the filter is only to make it clear what i want to achieve!

Comment: @JSelser:  I took a stab at addressing the syntax issues for OP.

Comment: @2ps It may sound counter-intuitive, but your proposed edit actually changes the meaning of the question (and the content of the resulting answers), since part of addressing OP's question involves pointing out the errors. In this case it's best to leave the code in the question as-is. Here is some further reading on how code in questions should and shouldn't be edited:  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260246/2234742 Thanks!

Comment: Yes, so now I need to edit my answer because people reading it won't understand the context that previously the JSON array was wrong.

Comment: @Toddsden Hopefully you don't mind, I've just reverted edits on both the question and your answer so that the question reflects the asker's actual code again and so your answer is consistent with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example based on your code. I made some key changes:

1. Your array of data is an array of objects.
2. I changed country to a value in your filter object. If you still
   want it to be an array then just change the code in the custom
   filter to work like it does for languages.

```js
    var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

    app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.data= [
            {
                'gender': 'male',
                'languages': ['German', 'English'],
                'country': 'Marocco'
            },
            {
                'gender': 'female',
                'languages': ['German', 'French'],
                'country': 'Kosovo'
            }
        ];
    }]);

    // Custom filter for our objects
    app.filter('myFilter', function () {
        return function (people, filterPerson) {
            var filtered = [];

            // Check if any elements in checkArray are in sourceArray
            var includesAny= function(checkArray,sourceArray){
                checkArray.forEach(function(element) {
                    if (sourceArray.includes(element)){return true;}
                });
                return false;
            };

            for (var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
                var person = people[i];
                if (filterPerson.country && filterPerson.country != person.country) {
                    continue;
                }

                if (filterPerson.gender && filterPerson.gender != person.gender) {
                    continue;
                }

                if (filterPerson.languages && includesAny(filterPerson.languages,person.languages)) {
                    continue;
                }

                filtered.push(person);
            }
            return filtered;
        };
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>AngularJS Example</title>

    <!-- AngularJS -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>


</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">

<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <h1>Unfiltered Data</h1>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="person in data">
            {{ person }}
        </li>
    </ul>

    <h1>Filtered Data</h1>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="person in data | myFilter:{'languages': ['Urdu', 'French'], 'country': 'Kosovo'}">
            {{ person }}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```